# ball hitting the glove of batsman but glove is not in contact with the bat. is it out?

Tags: rules, cricket

if the ball hits the glove of the batsman and the hand is not in contact with the bat and the ball is caught by the fielder will it be given as a out or not out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its not out ,possible only when ball hits glove of batsman while hand is in contact with bad .

***Reference:***http://news.bbc.co.uk/sport2/hi/cricket/rules_and_equipment/4176002.stm

Answer (score 1):

## Caught - Not out

The hand holding the bat, or any glove on that hand, is considered "part of the bat" for determining whether the bat strikes the ball:

> **5.6.2** contact between the ball and any of 5.6.2.1 to 5.6.2.4
>
> ...
>
> 5.6.2.2 the batsman’s hand holding the bat
>
> 5.6.2.3 any part of a glove worn on the batsman’s hand holding the bat
>
> ...
>
> shall be regarded as the ball striking or touching the bat or being struck by the bat.

By omission, therefore, it does not count a hand or glove that is not holding the bat.

To be out Caught requires the bat to touch or strike the ball, among other conditions:

> **33.1** Out Caught
>
> The striker is out Caught if a ball delivered by the bowler, not being a No ball, **touches his/her bat** without having previously been in contact with any fielder, and is subsequently held by a fielder as a fair catch, as described in 33.2 and 33.3, before it touches the ground.

Therefore, the batsman is not out Caught.

---

## Obstructing the field - maybe Out!

A batsman who willfully plays the ball with a hand holding the bat, except for specific circumstances listed in the laws, has met the conditions of Law 37:

> **37.1 Out Obstructing the field**
>
> ...
>
> 37.1.2 The striker is out Obstructing the field if, except in the circumstances of 37.2, in the act of receiving a ball delivered by the bowler, he/she wilfully strikes the ball with a hand not holding the bat.  This will apply whether it is the first strike or a second or subsequent strike.  The act of receiving the ball shall extend both to playing at the ball and to striking the ball more than once in defence of his/her wicket.
>
> ...
>
> **37.4** Returning the ball to a fielder
>
> Either batsman is out Obstructing the field if, at any time while the ball is in play and, without the consent of a fielder, he/she uses the bat or any part of his/her person to return the ball to any fielder.

The exceptions are listed in Law 37.2 Not out Obstructing the field, and amount to

- accidental obstruction
- avoiding injury
- the striker protecting their wicket, provided it doesn't interfere with a fielder trying to catch the ball

Therefore, the batsman may be either out or not out, depending on the circumstances.